# Pythonic way of looping values into variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've completed a project I was working on but I'm trying to find a way to make it more pythonic in a sense that takes less lines and well looks cleaner. I've been told before that if it isn't broken it shouldn't be fix but always looking for a better way to improve my programming.

So I have a tuple n with these values:

`n = ((100,200), (300,400),(500,600))
         for i, x in enumerate(n):
             if i is 0: D = x[0]
             if i is 1: M = x[0]
             if i is 2: s = x[0]
     print D, M, s`

where (D, M, s) should print out:

> 100, 300, 500

Is there a way to write those if statement since they are all going to be the first value always every time it loops through the tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage unpacking to accomplish this along with a list comprehension:

`D, M, s = [x[0] for x in n]`

This effectively loops through the list of tuples taking the first item and resulting in a list that now looks like: `[100, 300, 500]`

This is then unpacked in: `D, M, s`

Notice that the code is very simple, easy to read and doesn't require any other constructs to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension as follows:

```
n = ((100,200), (300,400), (500,600))    
print ', '.join([str(v1) for v1, v2 in n])
```

This would display:

```
100, 300, 500
```

It will also work when `n` is a different length.

Comment: i would like suggest  to use **list comprehension**  with ``join`` instead of **generator expression** since its more efficient http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/7742341

Answer (score 0):

```
n=((100,200),(300,400),(500,600))
D,M,s=n[0][0],n[1][0],n[2][0]
print(D,M,s,sep=" ,")
```

Comment: Please add more information and context. What does this code do and how does this answer the user's question? If you're going to make a code-only answer, the code needs to at least be well commented.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
D, M, s = zip(*n)[0]
```